# How to prevent android from automatically rearranging home screen icons?

Tags: applications, screen

I don't know in which which version of android this has been added but it seems like a really frustrating feature.

Once I delete an icon on my home screen, every other icon gets rearranged automatically towards the left top corner.

This is problematic because some of my apps are placed in a way that is easy to access with right thumb.

This means that every time I remove something from my home screen I need to manually rearrange all the icons back to how they ware, and I can't seem to find a setting that would fix this.

Version of Android - 6.0.1
But the same thing was happening in 5+
The smartphone I'm using is Sony Xperia Z3 compact.
As to the launcher I'm not sure which one Sony uses.

[image: Android home screen rearranging icons when removed]

Comment: This functionality is generally part of the Launcher - usually specific to the device and the OEM. So, please complete the question by supplying those missing details. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your additional info, the appropriate User Guide is on the [web](http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/d6616/userguide_AE_D6616_2_Android4.4.pdf). The specifics of handling apps and widgets on the Home Screen are covered on pages 14-17, with uninstalling in the last section. It makes no mention of the expected activity surrounding uninstalling apps, so any specific setting to control the app icon flow has to be related to the 'Own Order' setting, which it is apparent you know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps > the more button (3 dots placed vertically) > settings > turn off "automatically place icons together"

Comment: Works great! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Hold down on a blank space of the home screen until the settings option shows. Select settings, select automatically place icons together